# Is there any way to improve performance on using Handler and Runnable?

Tags: android, performance

I'm using Handler and Runnable to repeat one segment of the song, but it seems to drain the phone's battery because it is checking every millisecond. Here is my code:

Whenever user starts looping I do the following:

```
anotherHandler.post(mPlayLoopTask);
```

anotherHandler is a global variable declared at the top"

```
         private Handler anotherHandler = new Handler();
```

Here is my Runnable:

```
    private Runnable mPlayLoopTask = new Runnable() {


        public void run() 
           {

                if( mp != null)
                {
                    if( isLoopOn && start_position != -1 && end_position != -1 )
                    {
                        long currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();




                        if( currentPosition >=end_position )
                        {
                            mp.seekTo(start_position);
                        }
                    }


                    anotherHandler.post(this);
                }
           }
        };
```

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, there's always at least one Runnable in your Handler's queue. It's really an issue because the thread will continually execute the pending messages, not just once a frame.

Android AsyncTask with a sleep/wait is perhaps more appropriate in your case.

You can check the documentation and example here if needed: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: But I need to check every millisecond if the current position has passed what the user has picked for the end position. That is why there is always one runnable in the queue. I can't achieve that using AsyncTask.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a millisecond accuracy.
The user will not hear the difference if you check once every 250 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'd try the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class if I were you.

```
setLoopPoints(int startInFrames, int endInFrames, int loopCount)
```

Sets the loop points and the loop count.

```
setPlaybackHeadPosition(int positionInFrames)
```

Sets the playback head position.

```
setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener listener)
```

Sets the listener the AudioTrack notifies when a previously set marker is reached or for each periodic playback head position update.

```
setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener listener, Handler handler)
```

Sets the listener the AudioTrack notifies when a previously set marker is reached or for each periodic playback head position update.